# Routing is not working using react-router-dom-v6.4.2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

### Intro

I had created a react starter application

### Problem

I had created a 3 components in `/src/pages` named `AddCoupon`, `Addvertical`, `Addmetadata`. Now then I created a file `Routes.js` in `/src`.

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import AddCoupon from './pages/addCoupon';
import AddMetadata from './pages/addMetadata';
import AddVertical from './pages/addVertical';
import Login from './pages/login';


const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/addcoupon">
                        <AddCoupon />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/addmetadata">
                        <AddMetadata />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path='/addvertical'>
                        <AddVertical />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/">
                        <Login />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </>
    )
}

export default Routes
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router >
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

### What I want?

So basically what I want is that when I type `http:localhost:3000/addcoupon`, it should render `AddCoupon Component` and same for other 2 components but right now it's showing nothing.

I dont want to use any navbar. What I want is simply when I hit the endpoints mentioned in Route.js, it should render that component.

Comment: add exact to your Route elements

Comment: In all ROute elements??

Comment: if your url exactly will be for example /addvertical you should add exact to load exactly the defined component

Comment: @MagnusEffect I've updated my answer, I hope it will help now.

Comment: You cannot use Switch in react router v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router 6 uses different syntax compared to earlier versions. Please check out the documentation:
https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/overview

For your particular case, you need to remove switch, and pass element to route, and wrap all `Route` elements in `Routes` element, like so:

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/addcoupon" element={<AddCoupon />}/>
                <Route path="/addmetadata" element={<AddMetadata />}/>
                <Route path='/addvertical' element={<AddVertical />}/>
                <Route path="/" element={<Login />}/>
            </Routes>
        </>
    )
}
```

In order for routes to work, you also need to wrap `App` element in `Router` element, like below:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './App'
import './styles/index.scss'

ReactDOM.render(
   <Router>
      <App />
   </Router>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Final step, render `Routes` inside of `App` element or wherever you want to use it:

```
const App = () => {
   return <Routes/>
}
```

Comment: This is not working, I don't know why

Comment: Could you post your index.js file as well.

Comment: I have posted the index.js file.  In the final step, is `<Routes /> ` component that I had built or something from react-router-dom?

Comment: `<Routes /> ` is your component.

Comment: So to avoid confusion, I renamed it `RoutesComponent` and now its working. Thanks